# Retrieve number of lines in file from JFileChooser Java

Tags: java, swing, character, line, jfilechooser

Is there a way in Java to know the number of lines of a file chosen?
The method `chooser.getSelectedFile().length()` is the only method I've seen so far but I can't find out how to find the number of lines in a file (or even the number of characters)

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

--update--

```
long totLength = fc.getSelectedFile().length(); // total bytes = 284
double percentuale = 100.0 / totLength;         // 0.352112676056338
int read = 0;

String line = br.readLine();
read += line.length();

Object[] s = new Object[4];

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    s[0] = line;
    read += line.length();
    line = br.readLine();
    s[1] = line;
    read += line.length();
    line = br.readLine();
    s[2] = line;
    read += line.length();
    line = br.readLine();
    s[3] = line;
    read += line.length();
}
```

this is what I tried, but the number of the variable read at the end is < of the totLength and I don't know what File.length() returns in bytes other than the content of the file.. As you can see, here i'm trying to read characters though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Down and dirty:

```
long count =  Files.lines(Paths.get(chooser.getSelectedFile())).count();
```

You may find this little method handy. It gives you the option to ignore counting blank lines in a file:

```
public long fileLinesCount(final String filePath, boolean... ignoreBlankLines) {
    boolean ignoreBlanks = false;
    long count = 0;
    if (ignoreBlankLines.length > 0) {
        ignoreBlanks = ignoreBlankLines[0];
    }
    try {
        if (ignoreBlanks) {
            count =  Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).filter(line -> line.length() > 0).count();
        }
        else {
            count =  Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).count();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Damn that's really kinda deep for me, I'll first try something "easy". If I can't get out I'll try this too if though it's kinda complicated for me, not too good in Java :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `JFileChooser` to select a file, than open the file using a file reader and as you iterate over the file just increment a counter, like this...

```
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
    count++;
    file.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: I have to do stuff on lines but only after I know the number of lines.
With this solution I should twice the same job.. 
The problem with .length() of the File class doesn't return only the bytes of the content of the file, but also something else that I don't know, so if  I try to count the characters in bytes, I will have different values..

Comment: So `file.nextLine()` returns a string, you could take `file.nextLine().lenght()` and add that to a counter or could add it to an `ArrayList` and then you would know the number of characters in each of the lines. Hope that helps. I could change the answer to include that if it helps you out!

Comment: `file.nextLine()` Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname.